# Facebook Photo like + like on website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-like

I want to place a photo on my website and if someone will like that photo it should be liked on facebook too, how can it be done?

Comment: what did you do so far? What do you have as starting point?

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: no idk facebook api : ( can someone provide a little example?

Comment: Use the `Like Button` then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button